# Ubuntu DHCP client uses IDs instead of MAC addresses. Can't change this behavior

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I'm trying to use DHCP static lease assignment instead of manually managing static IPs for some of our servers. However Ubuntu switched from MAC addresses to some DHCP IDs becoming useless after major changes within the OS leading to getting fresh DHCP leases. Can see this at least on 18.04-23.04.

Googling around revealed adding 'send dhcp-client-identifier = hardware;' in the /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf But that didn't work.

Windows and Mac boxes still use MAC addresses. Have no idea why did Ubuntu change this mechanism especially for the server distro.

Comment: Ubuntu hasn't changed anything. The MAC does not need to be sent as part of the payload in the request because it is available in the ethernet frame anyhow. Your issue is in your Windows DHCP server. You just deleted your question that was closed, needing more clarity, and then asked the same thing again. It is the DHCP server that decides to supply an IP address based on MAC or from the pool of IP addresses.

Comment: the issue might be that Ubuntu no longer uses `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. Try adding `dhcp-identifier: mac` to your `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file (or whatever your file name is). I will test this myself and write an answer, but it will only be in a few hours. Via tcpdump, I do observe `Client-ID (61), length 19: hardware-type 255, 30:d1:36:0b:00:02:00:00:ab:11:c2:7e:3e:b1:15:66:00:36` from Ubuntu, but MAC's from other clients.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what exactly you are asking.  For every single Ubuntu installation I have done, I have used DHCP Reservations on my server using the MAC address of my Ubuntu installs by using the MAC address found by looking at `ip link` and then adding that to my DHCP server. These have been for installations of Ubuntu 20.04 and newer. I stopped using the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file and leave it in the default state where the `send` lines remain commented out.

Comment: As a test I just setup a Ubuntu 22.04 Server I did not modify the Netplan YAML file.  My DHCP server saw the MAC address of the 22.04 server and assigned it an IP address.  However, I did see the Client-ID only when the 22.04 server shutdown releasing the IP address that was in use clearing up the IP making it available.  From what I can see, the Client-IDs are very unique and another form of information for the DHCP server to keep things more straight.  So, the question is are you actually having issues assigning out DHCP Reservations to Ubuntu systems?

Comment: Thank you so much for this Doug! I've been searching quite long for this info. Going to test this.

PS: Indeed I resubmitted my question with different wording because that's what the site suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If your dhcp-server is configured to supply some IP addresses based on the MAC (Machine Address Code), then the `Client-ID` should be ignored and not matter what it is. If your Windows dhcp-server is using `Client-ID` when you have asked it to assign IP addresses based on the MAC then that would be a problem on that end. I have only ever used a linux based dhcp-server, and it has worked fine for MAC based IP address allocation since I first started using it with Ubuntu version 10.04.

Yes, by default Ubuntu now (I think since somewhere between versions 16.04 and 18.04) provides a `Client-ID` that is not the MAC. Example, from a 20.04 test server client, edited hopefully for better clarity:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -i br0 -vv port 67
tcpdump: listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
2023-12-31 08:30:22.423734 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 315)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83, length 287, xid 0x9399bc4d, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
          ...
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Client-ID (61), length 19: hardware-type 255, 30:d1:36:0b:00:02:00:00:ab:11:c2:7e:3e:b1:15:66:00:36
          ...
2023-12-31 08:30:22.423962 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.111.1.67 > 192.168.111.136.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x9399bc4d, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Your-IP 192.168.111.136
          Client-Ethernet-Address 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
          ...
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Offer
          ...
2023-12-31 08:30:22.424291 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 327)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83, length 299, xid 0x9399bc4d, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
            ...
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Request
            Client-ID (61), length 19: hardware-type 255, 30:d1:36:0b:00:02:00:00:ab:11:c2:7e:3e:b1:15:66:00:36
            ...
2023-12-31 08:30:22.424463 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.111.1.67 > 192.168.111.136.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x9399bc4d, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Your-IP 192.168.111.136
          Client-Ethernet-Address 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
            ...
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: ACK
```

Notice the client ID was:

```
30:d1:36:0b:00:02:00:00:ab:11:c2:7e:3e:b1:15:66:00:36
```

Now, if I add `dhcp-identifier: mac` to my `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file (your file might have a different name) like:

```
doug@s19:~/config/etc/netplan$ cat 01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [ enp3s0 ]
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp-identifier: mac
```

Then I get:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -i br0 -vv port 67
tcpdump: listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
2023-12-31 11:42:59.901076 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 303)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83, length 275, xid 0x8418f444, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
            ...
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Discover
            Client-ID (61), length 7: ether 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
            ...
2023-12-31 11:42:59.903551 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.111.1.67 > 192.168.111.136.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x8418f444, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Your-IP 192.168.111.136
          Client-Ethernet-Address 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
            ...
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Offer
            ...
2023-12-31 11:42:59.903851 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 315)
    0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83, length 287, xid 0x8418f444, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
            ...
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: Request
            Client-ID (61), length 7: ether 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
            ...
2023-12-31 11:42:59.904052 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    192.168.111.1.67 > 192.168.111.136.68: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x8418f444, secs 1, Flags [none] (0x0000)
          Your-IP 192.168.111.136
          Client-Ethernet-Address 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
            ...
            DHCP-Message (53), length 1: ACK
```

Notice that now the client ID is the MAC:

```
3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83
```

Since my dhcp-server is running on a different linux server configured to allocate some IP addresses based on the MAC, also notice that the change made no difference to the assigned IP address of 192.168.111.136

For reference, the relevant entry on the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file on the server for the MAC based IP address allocation:

```
host s19 {
  hardware ethernet 3c:7c:3f:0d:99:83;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.136;
}
```

[Reference](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/netplan-yaml/) (search for `dhcp-identifier`)